# Is the following method of insert Vec to hash map efficient?

Tags: substrate, polkadot

I have following variable in decl_storage:

```
Candidate get(fn candidate_name): map hasher(blake2_128_concat) T::AccountId => Vec<u8>;
```

This is my decl_module function:

```
    #[weight = 10_000 + T::DbWeight::get().reads_writes(2,2)]
    pub fn add_peers_to_deparment(origin, departmentid: u128) -> dispatch::DispatchResult {
        let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;
        let mut approved_peer_dep = PeerDepartments::<T>::get(&who);

        match approved_peer_dep.binary_search(&departmentid) {

            Ok(_) => Err(Error::<T>::DepartmentExists.into()),
            Err(index) => {
                approved_peer_dep.insert(index, departmentid.clone());
                PeerDepartments::<T>::insert(&who,approved_peer_dep);
                Self::deposit_event(RawEvent::PeerDepartment(departmentid, who));
                Ok(())
             }

        }
     }
```

Here I am writing two statements, first inserting `departmentid` to `approved_peer_dep` and then again inserting approved_peer_dep to the blockchain storage `PeerDepartments`.

```
approved_peer_dep.insert(index, departmentid.clone());
PeerDepartments::<T>::insert(&who,approved_peer_dep);
```

The doubt is if `approved_peer_dep` contains a very large `Vec`, will the blockchain (`PeerDepartments`) insert the complete Vec containing all the departments using more resources, or will used use resource of adding a single department? If it will use more resource what will be the better way to write the code.

How to have a data structure, so that I can access the Vec through a key and update it?

Answer (score 0):

As a start, here are a few resources to help you decide the path forward:

- For storage maps: [transparent keys in substrate](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate/transparent-keys-in-substrate/) (blog)
- For [storage best practices](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/runtime/storage#best-practices) (docs)
- A very good [deep dive on storage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKKOL20FdII) (video)

Comment: I am unable to be sure. It says, it hashes only the storage name, instead of storage value. So the code should work fine?